# How to make changes in Jenkins "Global configuration" page? (page is read-only)

Tags: jenkins

I am running an instance of Jenkins (I have all privileges), and trying to create and add a shared library of Groovy Pipeline code.  There seems to be a way to do this through the UI by clicking the "Global Configuration" found on the left-hand side of the root Jenkins page.  (This is not the "Manage Jenkins" link - that link works just fine.)

When I click on "Global Configuration", there are all sorts of things it appears I can configure, but every item seems to be disabled.  When I type in the description box, no characters appear.  When I check a checkbox, it doesn't changed to checked.  The "Add" button way way down in "Global Pipeline Libraries" (in fact, all of the buttons) is disabled and cannot be pressed.

I'm sure I'm missing something terribly obvious, but I just can't find it.  Any ideas why the global configuration page would be read-only for a Jenkins administrator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link on the main Jenkins page for "Global configuration" appears to bring up a page identical to the page accessed from "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure system" (very first link!).

When accessed via "Global configuration" it is read-only.

When accessed via "Manage Jenkins" -> "configure system" it can be edited.

Two days of head-scratching, and I only figure it out AFTER I save the question here.  At least, I hope this head-scratching exercise helps somebody else!

Comment: You can't type it in the url bar it seems.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins 2.440.2 the path is: `Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Tools or` /manage/configureTools/`